# PyCharm does not effectively recognize methods via dot operator

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm

I use PyCharm but I don't know why it does not recognize methods via `dot` operator? I don't see the list method when I hit `dot` of an object especially from classes that I imported (I see few but not all of them, sometimes none!!). Is there something in the Setting I should activate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main setting for listing methods for a class is the `Autopopup code completion` which it can be found under `Settings -> Code Completion` per the image below:

[image: pycharm settings]

Make sure that this setting is selected.

If this is already selected then probably your issue is caused because Pydev doesn't recognize the type of the variable, per the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218778/pydev-code-completion-for-everything).